# Can I check for transactions in an Uncle Block?

Tags: transactions, uncle-blocks

I am writing a script which will crawl through all the transactions in each block one by one, and identify deposits made to a specific address. My question is, should I be checking for transactions that might be included in uncle blocks as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because transactions in uncle blocks are not part of the Ethereum transaction history.

Comment: This is not true. transactions in uncle blocks are returned to the mempool and will be included in later blocks. We can also access them by calling `eth_getBlockByHash`.